# How do I manipulate a copy of NSDictionary's contents without changing the contents of original

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, pointers, pass-by-reference

**EDIT**

The following "simpler" code works as expected.  See the code below with explanation of my observations within comments.

```
- (void) changeDictValue
{
//If the method just uses the line below, then calling changeDictValue has no impact on self.bcastSeqNumList
NSMutableDictionary *seqListToUpdate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.bcastSeqNumList] ;

//But if it instead uses the line below, calling changeDictValue does change self.bcastSeqNumList  
NSMutableDictionary *seqListToUpdate = self.bcastSeqNumList ;

seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)]=@(0) ;
seqListToUpdate[@(maxRcvdSeqType)]=@(1) ;
seqListToUpdate[@(missingSeqType)]=nil ;

}
```

So, it looks like there is some bug in my code below (or some special Obj-C logic on how NSSets are handled during a calling on dictionaryWithDictionary:) that causes the NSSet associated with the missingSeqType key to be affected even though I am doing the manipulations on a new dictionary derived from self.bcastSeqNumList.  Any clues?

**END EDIT**

I have a `NSDictionary` that represents sequence numbers.
1. One key (lastContSeqType) represents the largest sequence number X such that I have received all the sequence numbers <=X
2. One key (maxRcvdSeqType) represents the maximum sequence number I have received till now
3. One key (missingSeqType) represents a set of "missing sequence numbers"

I have one such dictionary for "broadcast messages" and one such dictionary for each unicast message with a far-end.

When I get a list of stored sequence numbers from the server, I use stored the sequence number list at my end and the received sequence number list to determine which sequence numbers to retrieve.

When I execute following lines of code,

In The first implementation of *getMissingSequenceNumsFromServer:(NSDictionary *) dict*, things are working as expected, the `bcastSeqNumList` is getting updated, `lastContSeqType` is updated to 4 and `missingSeqType` is empty.

In the second implementation, where I create a new dictionary from the contents of self.`bcastSeqNumList` and then manipulate this "copied" Dictionary, I don't expect self.`bcastSeqNumList` to be affected by any of the manipulations inside the method.  I am seeing that `lastContSeqType` key is unaffected, but the `missingSeqType` key is affected and becomes an empty list (i.e the `NSNumber` object @(4) is being removed).  Why is this happening?

```
self.bcastSeqNumList= [@{@(lastContSeqType) : @(1), @(maxRcvdSeqType) : @(6), @(missingSeqType) : [NSMutableSet setWithObject:@(4)]
                                        } mutableCopy];

  NSLog(@"Bcast seq num list = %@",self.bcastSeqNumList) ;

  NSMutableDictionary *rcvdDict= [@{@"currBroadcastSeqNumStart" : @(5), @"currBroadcastSeqNumEnd" : @(6)
                             } mutableCopy];

  [self getMissingSequenceNumsFromServer:rcvdDict] ;

  NSLog(@"Bcast seq num list = %@",self.bcastSeqNumList) ;
```

**Case 1 Implementation**

```
- (void) getMissingSequenceNumsFromServer:(NSDictionary *) dict
{   
    NSInteger serverStoreSeqStart=[dict[@"currBroadcastSeqNumStart"] integerValue] ;
    NSInteger serverStoreSeqEnd=[dict[@"currBroadcastSeqNumEnd"] integerValue] ;
    NSMutableDictionary *seqListToUpdate = self.bcastSeqNumList ;


    NSInteger mySeq = [seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)] integerValue] ;


    if(mySeq < serverStoreSeqStart-1)
    {
        //Ask for all stored messages in server
        //[self getMessagesfromStart:serverStoreSeqStart toEnd:serverStoreSeqEnd] ;
        NSLog(@"Getting messages from %ld and to %ld",serverStoreSeqStart,serverStoreSeqEnd) ;

        NSLog(@"Never received seq nums %ld to %ld",mySeq+1,serverStoreSeqStart-1) ;

        NSInteger nextSeqToRemove ;


      for(nextSeqToRemove=mySeq+1;nextSeqToRemove<=serverStoreSeqStart-1;nextSeqToRemove++)
       {

         if([seqListToUpdate objectForKey:@(missingSeqType)])
         {
          if([seqListToUpdate[@(missingSeqType)] containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:nextSeqToRemove]])
           {
             NSLog(@"SeqNum %ld is in missing seq num list and being removed since we got server seq %ld > than this",(long)nextSeqToRemove,(long)serverStoreSeqStart) ;
            //Remove it
                            [seqListToUpdate[@(missingSeqType)] removeObject:@(nextSeqToRemove)] ;//
                            //If set is empty
                            if([seqListToUpdate[@(missingSeqType)] count] ==0)
                            {
                                //Nothing left in missing seq table. set it to nil and return
                                [seqListToUpdate removeObjectForKey:@(missingSeqType)] ;
                                seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)]=seqListToUpdate[@(maxRcvdSeqType)] ;
                                NSLog(@"Missing seq num list empty.  Setting last contig to max = %@",seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)]) ;

                                break ;
                            }
                 }
               }
               else
               {
                   //mising Seq Type has no elements, nothing to remove
                        break ;
               }
             }

             //At the end..if serverSeqToStore >= maxSeq, then lastCOnt=maxSeq and missing seq empty.
             //Else...if missing seq Empty, then

             seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:serverStoreSeqStart-1] ;

             if(seqListToUpdate[@(maxRcvdSeqType)] <= seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)])
             {
                    seqListToUpdate[@(maxRcvdSeqType)] = seqListToUpdate[@(lastContSeqType)] ;
                    //Set to misisng seq num list = nil
             }
             else
             {
                    //remove seqnums

             }
    }
    else if (mySeq < serverStoreSeqEnd)
    {
        //[self getMessagesfromStart:mySeq+1 toEnd:serverStoreSeqEnd] ;
        NSLog(@"Getting messages from %ld and to %ld",mySeq+1,serverStoreSeqEnd) ;
    }
    else if (mySeq > serverStoreSeqEnd)
    {
        NSLog(@"My stored sequence number %ld exceeds the max stored at server %ld",(long)mySeq,(long)serverStoreSeqEnd) ;
    }
}
```

**Case 2 Implementation**

The following line

```
    seqListToUpdate = self.bcastSeqNumList ;
```

is replaced by the line below so that any changes to `seqListToUpdate` should not affect the contents of `self.bcastSeqNumList`

```
    seqListToUpdate = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.bcastSeqNumList] ;
```

Comment: It is very hard to follow your code, but what is stored in the dictionary for the `missingSeqType` key?  Is it an array or another dictionary?  Copying the dictionary won't copy the objects that are inside it; the copy of the dictionary will contain the same object references as the original dictionary, so if you manipulate an array, you are simply manipulating the same array that is referenced by both dictionaries

Comment: Yes, because the new dictionary holds a reference to the same set, so you aren't changing the dictionary, you are changing the set

Comment: Thanks. Tried simplified version of the code, see edit. With this code, I see that changes to the new dictionary dont affect the dictionary from which it is created.  I thought I will have to use - initWithDictionary:copyItems:YES, to make the new dictionary independent of the original, but this seems unnecessary based on the result of my experiment with the simplified code. Looks like we need some Obj-C guru to explain what is happening!

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please explain your new comment?  I.e Suppose I create a new dictionary from self.bcastSeqNumList by using dictionaryWithDictionary.  And then I change one of the values in this new dictionary (that happens to be  a NSSet / NSArray etc),  do you expect the changes to affect the same value in  self.bcastSeqNumList?

Comment: Dictionaries hold references to objects, so when you copy a dictionary, the new dictionary contains the same object references, so if I change the referenced object (the set in your case) then all dictionaries that hold that reference will see the change because there is only one set. If I assign a new set to the key in the new dictionary then there are now two objects and I can change them independently.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.  Basically, in simplified code I was setting the NSSet associated with the key to nil.  So, this became the "assigning a new set creates two new objects" case.  In my original code, I was just manipulating the set and so all the changes were affecting self.bcastSeqNumList too.  Is that correct?  Also, to get the new dictionary to have a new NSSset with same values as in the original dictionary (but not reference the same NSSet as the original dictionary), Do I have to explicitly create a a new NSSet and assign it to the new dictionary or is there any easier way?

Comment: Things seem to "almost work" if I use NSMutableDictionary *seqListToUpdate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.bcastSeqNumList copyItems:YES] ;  However, it looks like the set that gets created is not a MutableSet and so I am not able to remove objects.  How do I make it a mutable set?

Comment: There is no single statement that will do it. You need to make a new mutable set based on the current set and assign that to the dictionary

Comment: Thanks, can you make your comments an answer, so that I can accept it?  Also, one last Q.  In the case of the other two keys which held NSNumbers, it looks like creating a new dictionary with dictionaryWithDictonary automatically led to the creation of an independent NSNUmber object whose manipulation did not affect the NSNUmber object in the original dictionary.  Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a deep copy. At the moment, you're just copying the references to the same objects. You also have to copy the objects, that are referenced in the dictionary.

The [easiest way of doing a deep copy is using `NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3) to archive and unarchive.

```
NSDictionary* deepCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:
      [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:originalDict]];
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a single statement that will do this deep copy? or do I have to create a new object from the existing one and then add it to the new dictionary?

Comment: You can use `NSKeyedArchiver ` as I just added to the answer. You might have to write the methods to conform to `NSCoding`. Or you can just write your own deep copy method.

Comment: Thanks this works.  Even when I don't do deep copy, it looks like if key has a NSNumber as its value, it is automatically deep-copied.  I.e if I change the NSNumber associated with the key in the new dictionary, the original dictionary is unchanged.  Why is this?

Comment: It's probably a side effect of optimizations. The value of `NSNumber` isn't stored in an object, but directly in the pointer using [tagged pointers](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.